# List of dinosaurs synonyms

Tags: taxonomy, nomenclature, palaeontology

Is there a comprehensive list of dinosaurs synonyms with indications of which name is now considered correct? Something like "there's no brontosaurus, there's only Apatosaurus", "there's no Anatotitan, there's only Edmontosaurus" and so on.

Comment: [Here is one list](http://www.dinosaurcentral.com/genera_list.php) that includes synonyms, but I don't know how credible it is and it seems to lack references. [Encyklopedia of Life](http://eol.org/pages/4531260/names) also includes information on synonyms (see link for Apatosaurus)- not a list but searchable.

Comment: Just for fun: [This TED talk](http://www.ted.com/talks/jack_horner_shape_shifting_dinosaurs) might be slightly related to your question.

Comment: Thank you Remi, this TED talk that i saw a few days ago is exactly what made me ask the question. I am creating a board game about dinosaurs and i need several names but i don't want to have two dinosaurs with different names that are actually the same dinosaurs and this is why i am here. I need a list, not a directory, just for convenience, because it would be so much more easier to scroll a list instead of looking for 120 different names (this is the current size of my dinosaur "pool"). thank you anyways!

Comment: @JohannesWentu For that use, the second list in my answer should be sufficient. It seems like several professional paleontologists are included in the project.

Comment: Actually, a paper in 2015 resurrected Brontosaurus as a valid genus. What is surprising is that the "thunder lizard" was smaller than the dully-named Apatosaurus.

Answer (score 2):

[Encyclopedia of Life](http://eol.org/pages/4531260/names) includes information on synonyms (see link for Apatosaurus) - not a list but searchable and often with references and background info. After a quick google search I also found [this list from dinosaurcentral.com](http://www.dinosaurcentral.com/genera_list.php), but I don't know how credible and updated it is and it seems to lack references.